# How to get the latency number of flink job

Tags: apache-flink

I know flink collects latency metrics out of box, but I want to know how can I get the latency data of my job.

Do I have to use custom reporter(e.g. graphite) to view the latency?

I saw there is latency metrics in flink dashboard, but no data when I added the latency of a sink operator. 
If this is not the latency data, what is it?

Thank you.

I am using Flink V1.2.1 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flink dashboard can only display single values. But you can examine the latency by using the REST api. The URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/jobs/f184a26ee033d5448042c18de57499a1/vertices/91f34222e409e97879611b1fd334816e/metrics?get=0.Sink__Unnamed.latency
```

And the reply will look like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "0.Sink__Unnamed.latency",
    value: "{LatencySourceDescriptor{vertexID=1, subtaskIndex=0}={p99=416.0699999999999, p50=253.0, min=102.0, max=421.0, p95=378.04999999999995, mean=249.953125}}"
  }
]
```

You can use `http://localhost:8081/jobs/` to find your job id, and then `http://localhost:8081/jobs/<job-id>/vertices/` to choose an operator in your execution graph. `http://localhost:8081/jobs/<job-id>/vertices/<operator-id>/metrics` will show the available metrics.

Comment: From Flink 1.5 onwards the endpoint is /jobs/metrics (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50982071/1236613).