# Flink latency metrics not being shown

Tags: apache-flink

While running Flink 1.5.0 with a local environment I was trying to get latency metrics via REST (with something similar to `http://localhost:8081/jobs/e779dbbed0bfb25cd02348a2317dc8f1/vertices/e70bbd798b564e0a50e10e343f1ac56b/metrics`) but there isn't any reference to `latency`.

All of this while the latency tracking is enabled which I confirmed by checking with the debugger that the `LatencyMarksEmitter` is emiting the marks.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.5 latency metrics aren't exposed for tasks but for jobs instead, the reasoning being that latency metrics inherently contain information about multiple tasks. You have to query "http://localhost:8081/jobs/e779dbbed0bfb25cd02348a2317dc8f1/metrics" instead.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! As a follow-up: "latency.source_id.X.source_subtask_index.0.operator_id.Y.operator_subtask_index.3.latency_p95" means "95th percentile of the source X -> operator Y (task 4/4) path" right?

Comment: well...kind of. It is the latency form X to Y; specifically from the 1st instance of X to the 4th instance of Y.